# dismiss launched viewControllers and return to initial view controller (storyboards)

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5, storyboard

I've seen this question a couple of times but never really answered.  I'm wondering if there is an acceptable/clean way to dismiss all launched view controllers and return to the initial view controller when using storyboards (say from an action within a spawned view controller).

I know how to use delegates, but, I'd prefer to not have my initial view controller implement delegates for every possible spawned view controller.  Instead, I'd just like a home button that cleans everything up and returns to the initial view controller from anywhere in the app.

Thoughts?

EDIT:  Just for clarity, assume I am NOT using UINavigation Controllers.

EDIT2:  Is it possible to just access the methods of the "initial view controller" from anywhere in the app like you might do with the appDelegate?

Answer (score 2):

This should do it at any point. Just stick it in an IBAction and hook it up to a button :)

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewController];
```

Comment: Isn't that just for UINavigation Controllers?  I'm not always using those.

Comment: If you've been using storyboards segues for pushing I believe it should work anyway as it is creating one for you.

Comment: I don't think it does--pushes crash without an underlying UINavigation Controller.  I'm just modally presenting view controllers (or, occasionally doing it programmatically).

Comment: If you're presenting chains of modals there is a much worse underlying design problem in your application then needing to pop to the root view controller.

Comment: @RyanPoolos: Is "chains of modals" the only pattern that would result in one not being strictly under navigation controllers?  For example, what if you have a TabBarController with two tabs, each having a navigation controller?  You could unwind within each tab's navigation controller individually, but that doesn't completely "start over" the flow of the app. What would be appropriate there?

Comment: The flow of the app is up to the user. Tabs are sequential so you would unwind the tab they're currently in, and leave them there. If they desire to switch tabs, they would do so normally by tapping the other tab. This is an important interface distinction. UINavigationController provides a flow for the user, UITabController provides options for the user.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a singleton.  Seems to work quite well.

On the initial load of the initial view controller, I set the view controller as the singleton's property.  I can then execute the following code in any action method on any view controller in the app to dismiss all view controllers and return to the initial view controller.

```
initialViewControllerManager *ivcManager = [initialViewControllerManager sharedInstance];
LPViewController *ivc = ivcManager.initalViewController;    
[ivc dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

May not be the "right" answer, but, seems to work.  And, given the complexity of my scenes, relying exclusively on UINavigationControllers would be very complicated.